Cannot delete LDAP user files in Ubuntu 22.04
I have been searching exhaustively for the answer to this question but haven't found any valid solution...
I work in an Ubuntu 22.04 machine which was already used before by another user. I want to remove the user and the files, as he told me is not using it anymore but still keeps storing files in this machine.
When I tried to delete the user using deluser as root, it was removed from /etc/passwd but still appears as user using getent.
Also, when I try to delete his files I get a constant error of Permission denied even if I am logged in as root. I also get messages like Operation cannot be performed on [file] when I use lsattr or chattr.
After some research I found that the files are owned by this user (obvious) who belongs to a specific group, which contains some other users not working in my machine. I tried to change his password, that's when I was asked for the LDAP password, so I figured out he is a LDAP user.
I am not sure if this is the reason because I cannot remove his files, any help of how to completely delete the user and his files?
